# matplotlib scatter plots are un-filled/incorrect color (Custom stylesheet)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, customization

I am trying to make a custom stylesheet([Nice.mplstyle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12GNmoh5mwTgifPadUZJIjI0RI3Ddw1md/view?usp=sharing) I modeled it after 'classic.mplstyle') for "publication quality plots", however when using my sheet with scatter plots it seems like it always colors the center of the scatter markers the incorrect color (blue). I would prefer solid color for my markers following the color cycler. As an aside, matplotlib also doesn't seem to recognise my custom color cycler either. Here is the code I use to test my plots:

````
import numpy as np
import scipy
import random

def fun(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.sin(b*(x + c))

depth = 500

X = np.linspace(0, 20, depth)
X3 = 0.5*(X+6)
Y = 15 * np.sin(X3)
nY = np.empty(depth)
rand0_1 = np.empty(depth)

for y in Y:
    
    i, = np.where(Y == y)
    rand1_2 = np.random.random() * 7
    rand0_1[i] = (-1) ** random.randrange(1, 3)
    nY[i] = Y[i] +(rand0_1[i] * rand1_2)
    

fitp, fitcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fun, X, nY, p0=[13, 0.3, 9])


plt.style.use('Nice.mplstyle')
# plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.scatter([X]*2, [nY, fun(X, *fitp)])
# plt.plot(X, fun(X, *fitp))
plt.xlim(0, max(X))
plt.ylim(min(nY)-5, max(nY)+5)```
````

Comment: I downloaded the Nice.mplstyle file but did not see any setting about the scatter-filling color.

Comment: I couldn't find any rcparam that set that color specifically so I guess that is the main issue.